# Exclusively choosing one of two paths in jmeter

Tags: webserver, jmeter, load-testing

In my jmx script, I want each thread to login once per thread only.  There are two methods for logging in.  90% of the time I want it to use method #1, 10% of the time I want it to use method #2.

How would I structure that?

If I use two `Throughput` controllers, isn't there a chance it could try to call both login methods in one thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 different samplers cannot be executed by one thread at the same time so it is fine to use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), I would configure it as follows:

- Throughput Controller (Percent Executions, 90.0)

  - Login which needs to be executed in 90% of times
- Throughput Controller (Percent Executions, 10.0)

  - Login which needs to be executed in 10% of times

"Per user" box does not matter in this case.

If you want to be totally sure that i.e. each 10th thread will go 2nd login path you can try alternative configuration:

- Login (90% times)
- [If Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) - Condition: `((${__threadNum} % 10) == 0)`

  - Login (10% times)

[__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) is JMeter function which returns current thread number so if current thread number is multiple of 10, the thread will go the "10% way"

P.S. I wouldn't recommend implementing approach by link of Mr. UBIK LOAD PACK as it works only for "2 VUs with Loop of 50" scenario for any other combination distribution will be different.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I have a ThreadGroup with two ThroughPut controllers directly below, as described in your answer.  I've seen cases where both controllers are executed and cases where neither is executed.  How do I make it mandatory that one of them must be chosen?

Comment: That's weird. In that case go for 2nd option. Put `Login (90% times)` under another If Controller and use `((${__threadNum} % 10) != 0)` as condition. Also it would be good if you could share your test plan, it looks like a JMeter issue

Comment: Yeah I've done a variation of your second method, which is working, thanks.  What's the best way to share the test plan?